# Fetching Data from a Json API endpoint and saving the data in an array. Basically Creating variables from Json data received from an API callback

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I am trying to fetch data from an api, saving the data into variables which i plan to finally save in the database. The problem is that the project is throwing errors which i have not been able to solve.

This code is for PHP and JSON. I am working on an online payment system and i want to save the data received from callbacks into my database. However, i am not able to do this because the data received in JSON format, is proving to be a headache extracting it.

Here is the **PHP code** of how i am extracting the variables:

`$amount=$callbackData->Body->CallbackMetadata->Item[0]->Value;
 $mpesaReceiptNumber=$callbackData->Body->stkCallback->CallbackMetadata->Item[1]->Value;
 $balance=$callbackData->Body->stkCallback->CallbackMetadata->Item[2]->Value;
 $b2CUtilityAccountAvailableFunds=$callbackData->Body->stkCallback->CallbackMetadata->Item[3]->Value;
 $transactionDate=$callbackData->Body->stkCallback->CallbackMetadata->Item[4]->Value;
 $phoneNumber=$callbackData->Body->stkCallback->CallbackMetadata->Item[5]->Value;`

**Here is the JSON Data:**

```
{
```

"Body":{
      "stkCallback":{
         "MerchantRequestID":"22571-1918158-1",
         "CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_DMZ_357840864_13022019182443436",
         "ResultCode":0,
         "ResultDesc":"The service request is processed successfully.",
         "CallbackMetadata":{
            "Item":[
               {
                  "Name":"Amount",
                  "Value":1.00
               },
               {
                  "Name":"MpesaReceiptNumber",
                  "Value":"NBD5TUW3AV"
               },
               {
                  "Name":"Balance"
               },
               {
                  "Name":"TransactionDate",
                  "Value":20190213182502
               },
               {
                  "Name":"PhoneNumber",
                  "Value":254727304011
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}

**Here is the error I am getting:**

[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$CallbackMetadata in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 25
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'Item' of non-object in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 25
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'Value' of non-object in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 25
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$CallbackMetadata in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 26
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'Item' of non-object in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 26
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'Value' of non-object in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 26
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$CallbackMetadata in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 27
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'Item' of non-object in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 27
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'Value' of non-object in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 27
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$CallbackMetadata in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 28
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'Item' of non-object in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 28
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'Value' of non-object in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 28
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$CallbackMetadata in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 29
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'Item' of non-object in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 29
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'Value' of non-object in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 29
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$CallbackMetadata in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 30
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'Item' of non-object in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 30
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'Value' of non-object in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 30
[13-Feb-2019 14:46:07 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/vinemupw/public_html/project/callbacks/stkcallback.php on line 64

Comment: My apologies, I am new and i have not been able to indent the content properly, I just need you to help me do the amount part, the rest i will code. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Did you json_decode the response ? Suggesting $data holds the json string you have to do

```
$arr = json_decode($data, true);
```

Then you can access the ResultCode for example with:

```
$arr['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultCode'];
```

To access the Item list

```
    $callbackMetadata = $data['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata'];
    $amount = $callbackMetadata['Item'][0];
```

As a note: The second parameter in json_decode defines if an assoc array or an object should be returned.

**Edit : The json you posted above has an invalide structure, did you maybe remove some values ?**

Comment: No, that is the actual Json that i am receiving. That is why i thing i am having a lot of problems with it Maybe.

Comment: If thats the actual data it wont work cause json_decode will return null if you put that json string in.

you can verfiy that here for example : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

You could add "JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR" as option to json_decode so you can see if invalid data are provided

Comment: I have edited the Json File, But I think your solution Will work, Let me try with the rest of the data and then if it works i will approve the above as the correct aswer, Thanks alot.